# SQL Update everytime column hits x number rows

Tags: sql-server

I have table call `question` with two columns, it contains more than 160K rows, example:

```
id | questionID
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3
4  | 4
5  | 5
6  | 6
7  | 7
8  | 8
9  | 9
10 | 10
...
```

I would like to update the questionID column so it will look like the example below. For every x number rows it need update to set from 1 again. The final result should be something like this:

```
id | questionID
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3
4  | 4
5  | 1
6  | 2
7  | 3
8  | 4
9  | 1
10 | 2
...
```

The table contains some many rows, so its not an option do it manually.
What could be the easiest way to update the table?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: Are the numbers really sequential with no gaps?

Comment: Sql server and number has no gaps. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use the modulus operator.  Both SQL Server and MySQL support `%`:

```
UPDATE question
    SET questionID =  1 + ((id - 1) % 4);
```

If the numbers have gaps, then you need to do something different.  In that case, the solution is highly database dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use modulo operator:

```
UPDATE question
SET questionID = CASE WHEN id  % 4 = 0 THEN 4 ELSE id % 4 END
```

or, if `id` has gaps *and you are using SQL Server*, then you can use this:

```
 UPDATE q1
 SET id = (CASE WHEN q2.rn % 4 = 0 THEN 4 ELSE q2.rn % 4 END)
 FROM question q1
 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by id) AS rn
     FROM question ) q2 ON q1.ID = q2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE question SET questionID = questionID % 4 + 1
```